# Filter on Search Message extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, imessage-extension

I am using Search Message extension to create my app, I also want a way to provide a filter to my user. I coudn't find a clear document if that is achievable. Is there any way to provide filters, similar to like this:

[Filter on Search Message Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZH6I.png)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of filter cannot be applied on messaging extension. Messaging extension have one search input. You can get more information from this doc: [Messaging Extension Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/design/messaging-extension-design#search-commands)